# How to determine if a Swing component is fully visible and not partly clipped by another component with a higher z-order

Tags: java, swing

Consider the following tree

```
--> rootFrame
  --> panelA
    --> panelA1
  --> panelB
    --> panelB1
    --> panelB2
```

panelB1 might become visible at some point depending on external factors. If that's the case, I want to know in panelA1 if panelB1 (or any other panel actually) is partly or fully overlapping panelA1.

I can't find a way to do so. In the paint of panelA1 I could fetch the clip bounds of the graphics object, but paint is not being called when a component gets overlapped.

Is there any way to A) determine if a component in Swing is fully visible to the user and B) get notified if this changes?

Comment: `paintComponents`? There is the hierarchy listener for adding/removing too. Sounds convoluted.

Comment: What external factors? This is your program. You are in control of when a component is made visible or not. Or you are in control is a component is dragged. So you add logic that whenever a component is made visible or dragged to you check to see if it now covers another component.

Comment: @camickr The application is part of a big (embedded) system and is an application with hundres of thousands of lines of code and hundreds of components that might show at some point depending on human interaction on the embedded device. I don't want to force any future developer that creates a new component to know about the fact that there's one component that wants to know about it's visibility. I want to push that logic to that specific component in a generic way preferably.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way for a component to know if a component has been painted over top of it.

The only think I can think of is to use an `AWTEventListener`. You can listen for events to determine if a component has been shown or moved.

So maybe whenever any of these events are generate you check if the bounds of this component intersects with the bounds of the component you are worried about.

Check out [Global Event Listeners](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for more information.